# Issues With SQL update statement in JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

code throws java.sql.SQLDataException: Invalid character string format for type INTEGER each time i run , i don't seem to know what the problem is

```
private void update(){
    connection();
    try{
        String sqldb = 
                "update votersInfo set votersName = ? , age = ?,state = ? where votersId =?"
                ;            
        prep = conn.prepareStatement(sqldb);

        //int intA = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());            
        prep.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText()));            
        prep.setString(2, jTextField2.getText());
        prep.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText()));
        prep.setString(4, jTextField4.getText());
        int a = prep.executeUpdate();
        if (a>0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Sucessful");
        }                                    
    }
    catch(Exception e){
       // System.err.println(e.printStackTrace());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the  stack trace print?

Comment: Did you check what the actual values of `jTextField1.getText()` and `jTextField3.getText()` are?

Comment: what is database column type for votersName, age,state and votersId? Check it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume votersId is an integer but you are directly sending an String instead of integer.

So modify your last preparedStatements as

```
prep.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(jTextField4.getText()));
```

Now run your code and check if it runs successfuly.

Answer (score 0):

You have a major argument mismatch. I've filled in the values here.

```
    String sqldb = 
            "update votersInfo set votersName = ? [1], age = ? [2] ,state = ? [3] where votersId =? [4]";
```

And how they map to your sets:

```
    prep.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText())); //setting name to an Integer
    prep.setString(2, jTextField2.getText()); //setting age to a String
    prep.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText())); //setting state to an Integer
    prep.setString(4, jTextField4.getText()); //setting votersId to a String
```

I don't know what your inputs are since you haven't told us what they are, but you should retailor them so they go to the correct spots. At the moment, you're assigning Strings to numeric fields and numerics to String fields, from what we can see.